# I need to know if the problem have an answer or if it was badly posed.

Tags: problem-solving

Daniel and Anna had visited Toledo and with their camera they had taken 45 pictures. Daniel appears in 15 of them, Anna in 26 and both in solely 7. In how many photos neither of them appear?

I´d really appreciate an answer.

Comment: You want $(A\cup B)^c$.

Comment: Sorry about my ignorance, but I don´t recognize the little exponential that you place after the bracket. What do you mean?

Comment: The complement of the set.

Comment: You **want** an answer. Do you also **want** to try by yourself ?

Comment: I´ve been trying, but I haven´t gotten anywhere. My knowledge about sets is really poor by these days.

Comment: A Venn diagram might help. You can work out the number of photos in each region of the diagram. It's definitely _not_ a badly posed problem.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. Even though it took me a lot of time, I made it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $X$ the set of all photos, $A$ the set of photos where Daniel appear and $B$ the set of photo where Anna appear. Then, $|X|=45$, $|A|=15$, $|B|=26$ and $|A\cap B|=7$. What is $|X\backslash (A\cup B)|$ ?